# How can I declare xpath locator in yaml page , and for that how can get text?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, yaml

Below is my code, both the tables having the same class names.

1. I want xpath locator for yaml page
2. I want to locator for "Start date" with out using the contains
3. Also how to get the text in web driver for the same

```
<table class="A"> 
    <tr style="height: 48px;"> 
        <td class="B" align="center">?</td> 
        <td align="left" class="B" style="color: #000; text-align: left;">start date</td> 
    </tr> 
</table>
   <table class="A" style="border-bottom: none;"> 
        <tr style="height: 48px;"> 
            <td class="B" align="center"> </td> 
            <td align="left" class="B" style="color: #000; text-align: left;">END date date</td> 
        </tr> 
    </table>
```

Comment: Programming language??

Comment: Please format the code so that it is easier for others to read.

Comment: "I want xpath locator for yaml page". What page with YAML (yes that is an acronym and written all caps) are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to locate using `xpath` with index as below

```
(.//table//td[@class = 'B' and @style])[1]
```

To getting text of this element call `.getText()`  after locating element.

Comment: if i check the same gettin the error  US: "(.//table//td[@class="A"])[1]"                plz tell me how to declare the locator in YAML